# Error serializing value

Tags: c#, serialization, viewstate

how to know where is this thing realy happen?

my abject are complicate for track and test each one , im sure there is a way to find the line of this problam no?

in my case im using viewstate that make this serialize , in my object there are some enum that are out of the class it might also made that issue?

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            object[] attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PersistToViewState), true);
            if (attributes.Length > 0)
                ViewState[property.Name] = property.GetValue(this, null);
        }

        return base.SaveViewState();
```

Comment: Does the compiler generate an error message? If so, please post it. If the error is that something doesn't work at run-time, please state what you expected to happen and what *actually* happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With serialisation errors, you need to see the inner exception for the actual detail. The real detail could be deep 4-5 levels but is always descriptive enough to find out what is wrong.

Put the full error stack if you need more help.

Comment: thanks i was in updatepanel and mask error so i couldnt see the exception